# PHP Support for Multiple SQL ( MySQL, MySQLi, PDO, etc.) in Single Class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to let the user select the best option (from their point of view) for a query language?  For example, when I run this: `$class->fetch(query);` I would like it to use MySQL functions if the user chose MySQL, PDO if the user chose PDO, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_Db (from the Zend Framework) does what you want.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html

As always with the ZF, you don't need the entire Framework for a single module. :-)

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, yes, you can.

Comment: how can i download this single module

Comment: why cut the code? why not just include the entire library and use autoloading?

Comment: i think these classes depend on the zf libs